# How to overdraw on WPF tab control

Tags: wpf-controls

I am wondering how to draw beyond the boundaries of the standard WPF tab control?  I have tried the various ClipToBounds settings and inserted my control within a canvas, which has worked for me with a grid in the past.  Sample XAML:

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="MainWindow"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Grid>
    <TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="90,31,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100">
            <Canvas Margin="10,26,-10,-26">
                <Ellipse Width="25" Height="25" Fill="Red" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0"></Ellipse>
            </Canvas>
    </TabControl>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but this answer solved the problem for me. You can use this template and just change the Grid's ClipsToBounds to False. https://zamjad.wordpress.com/2010/05/05/use-different-panel-in-tab-control/